# Qualified input but checked invalid by `form.is_valid`

Tags: django

I input qualified content to form but was checked as invalid by  `form.is_valid`,

Here is my views:
I add `print(request.POST) # test input` to check `post`ed successfully, and  `print("form is invalid.") #assert invalid` to check if it's a valid form,

```
class CommentCreateView(View):

    template_name = "article/article_detail.html"

    def get(self, request, pk):
        return redirect(f"/article/detail/{ pk }")

    def post(self, request, pk):

        self.article = Article.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST) # test input

        if form.is_valid():
            print("form is valid.")  #assert valid
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            print(f"Comment: {form.cleaned_data}")
            comment.owner = request.user
            comment.article = self.article
            comment.status = 0
            comment.save()
            return redirect(f"/article/detail/{ pk }")
        else:
            print("form is invalid.") #assert invalid
            comments = (Comment.objects
                            .filter(article=self.article, status=0)
                            )
            context = {'article': self.article,
                        'comments':comments,
                        "form": form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

The `Comment` model data`:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (0,  'normal'),
        (-1, 'deleted'),
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField() # set the widget
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

And the forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment', 'date_created']
        widgets = {'comment': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

The error report:

```
Django version 1.11.13, using settings 'forum.settings'
Starting development server at http: // 127.0.0.1: 8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['jL9aDh0cSNgvlmGWtI5sogFlruIvLh4rHqt0jll2V3H70Bel35IDFq6cgkWhAJHK'], 'comment': ['issue a test']} >
form is invalid.
[09/Jun/2018 13:12:32] "POST /article/comment/create/17 HTTP/1.1" 200 4183
```

It checked that the form is invalid.

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: What do you mean with *how to solve such a problem*? Either you made the checks to restrictive, or the form is invalid, and thus the user should fix the content they send (you can print the `form.errors` to help the user with that).

Comment: At first sight, it looks like you did not provide the `date_created` parameter.

Comment: ty,I altered charfield to textfield but not made migrations  @WillemVanOnsem